# Noisy observations of independent signals are independent?

Tags: independence, measurement, noise

Assume 10 signals are transmitted each day derived from the same distribution randomly, and as such are considered independent from each other.  Each signal is measured by 10 different monitors each adding a noise to the signal.  Are the set of 100 measurements mutually independent and pairwise independent?  Are there some conditions where they would not be independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generating functions are independent, so the signals are independent. However, you did not state that the noise introduced by the monitors were all purely white (or anything else). If there are peculiarities in the noise introduced by *specific* monitors, some correlation could be introduced, the strength of which being dependent on the signal/noise ratio of the monitors. For instance, suppose monitor 1 had 50Hz line noise while monitor 2 had 60Hz line noise, and your measurement involved frequency spectra. The signals recorded by monitor 1 may retain some correlation structure.